# C# : Retrieve Json Data Structure even if no data in it

Tags: c#, json, dataset

I'm heavily using json to retrieve data from Rest API into Datasets (convert json to xml and then load xml into dataset) but the issue I'm facing is when no data is present in some attributes, there is no related attribute name (aka column name) created in the dataset.
My question is: is there any way to overcome this limitation and to force json to get the attribute name even if no data in it?

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] demonstrating your problem?  See: [ask].